# Android: Size bucket not correctly selected (for 720x1280 screen resolution devices)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an app whose layout work pretty much on all devices except for Android Note II mainly because of some reported padding issues.

After looking up the specs for the device, I determined that screen size for this device is 720x1280 and added a dimens.xml file into the values bucket that would match this configuration:

```
values-w720dp-h1280dp/dimens.xml
```

I fired up an emulator on Manymo.com and selected a device with a screen 720x1280 (320dpi) and ran my app and it seems that Android always picks up the default dimens.xml (i.e. `values/dimens.xml`) and never `values-w720dp-h1280dp/dimens.xml`

Since I don't have a physical device to test this out on, I'm reliant on emulating this. Is this an issue on the emulator or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the device is 720px x 1280px at 320 dpi it should be 360dp x 640dp

Comment: Assuming you mean the Galaxy Note II. Unless there is an Android Note II I'm not familiar with. Other than that, zapl's comment is the answer. The qualifier is in dp, not in pixels.

Comment: Adding dimens.xml to values-w360dp doesn't seem to have any effect either :/